# Postgis - how to have the start point of a polygon simplified

Tags: postgresql, postgis, simplify

I'm using ST_Simplify to simplify some polygons. It works well with most of them, but I have some polygons with an unnecessary start point that I'd like removed.

Here is an example with a polygon that can be simplified :

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Simplify(ST_GeomFromText(
    'POLYGON((0 0, 5 0, 10 0, 10 10, 0 10, 0 0))'
    ), 1))
```

And here is an example with an equivalent polygon (same points, different start point) that can't be simplified :

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Simplify(ST_GeomFromText(
    'POLYGON((5 0, 10 0, 10 10, 0 10, 0 0, 5 0))'
    ), 1))
```

I'm not expecting the Douglas-Peucker algorithm (ST_Simplify) to change the start point or end point of a polygon. What should I do to have the second polygon simplified ?

*EDIT*
I may have some concave polygons:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Simplify(ST_GeomFromText(
    'POLYGON((5 0, 10 0, 8 8, 10 10, 0 10, 0 0, 5 0))'
    ), 1))
```

Comment: Douglas-Peucker explicitly keeps the start and end point, so this is expected behavior. Jakub's solution certainly works in this case, but there might be instances where it would remove too many points. Could you expand on potential polygons you might have?

Comment: An actual polygon I have this problem with: `POLYGON((0.3440795473 46.5839586882, 0.3440429858 46.5839209648, 0.3440874524 46.5839006522, 0.3444448921 46.5837370397, 0.3444897180 46.5837165418, 0.3445262795 46.5837541419, 0.3445360711 46.5837644525, 0.3444964554 46.5837826660, 0.3443921610 46.5838303915, 0.3441933638 46.5839213352, 0.3441325479 46.5839491801, 0.3440894287 46.5839688753, 0.3440795473 46.5839586882))`

Comment: Sorry, that is quite hard to read, the first and last points are the same (but this is required for it to be a valid polygon). Which other point would you want to get rid off using ST_Simplify and are you prepared to use plpgsql to do so?

Comment: Simplified result : `POLYGON((0.3440795473 46.5839586882,0.3440429858 46.5839209648,0.344489718 46.5837165418,0.3445360711 46.5837644525,0.3440894287 46.5839688753,0.3440795473 46.5839586882))`, expected result is the same without the start/end point. For now I only have a problem with the start/end point, ST_Simplify takes good care of the other extra points. I can use pgplsql.

Comment: When you run, select st_isvalid(st_geomfromtext('POLYGON((0.3440795473 46.5839586882,0.3440429858 46.5839209648,0.344489718 46.5837165418,0.3445360711 46.5837644525,0.3440894287 46.5839688753))')); you get an error: geometry contains non-closed rings. I don't see how you can simplify that polygon and keep it valid, seeing as repeated start and end points are required by definition for it to be a valid polygon

Comment: I rephrase: expected result is the same without the start point, and with the end (closing) point changed to the new start point.

Comment: Answer posted. I hope that works for you. I had to use a tolerance of 0.0001 to get sensible answers from the polygon you posted in comments, but it works as expected for the one from your original question with a tolerance of 1.

Comment: any thoughts on this? I am about to disappear for a couple of weeks, so if you have any issues, let me know soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the example from John Barça, adding a distance test to simplify the closing point, and making that work for all geometries, I get this solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION simplify_geometry(geom geometry, tolerance float)
  RETURNS geometry AS
$BODY$

DECLARE geomType text;
DECLARE simplified geometry;
DECLARE testSegment geometry;
DECLARE simplifiedElements geometry[];

BEGIN

  geomType := GeometryType(geom);

  IF ST_IsEmpty(geom) THEN
    RETURN geom;
  ELSIF geomType ~ '(MULTI|COLLECTION)' THEN
    simplifiedElements := array(SELECT simplify_geometry((ST_Dump(geom)).geom, tolerance));
    RETURN ST_Collect(simplifiedElements);
  ELSIF geomType = 'LINESTRING' THEN
    simplified := ST_Simplify(geom, tolerance);

    IF ST_IsClosed(simplified) THEN
      testSegment := ST_MakeLine(ST_PointN(simplified, 2), ST_PointN(simplified, ST_NPoints(simplified)-1));
      IF ST_Distance(ST_StartPoint(simplified), testSegment) < tolerance THEN
        simplified := ST_RemovePoint(simplified, 0);
        simplified := ST_RemovePoint(simplified, ST_NPoints(simplified)-1);
        simplified := ST_AddPoint(simplified, ST_StartPoint(simplified));
      END IF;
    END IF;

    RETURN simplified;
  ELSIF geomType = 'POLYGON' THEN
    simplifiedElements := array(SELECT simplify_geometry(ST_ExteriorRing((ST_DumpRings(geom)).geom), tolerance));
    RETURN ST_MakePolygon(simplifiedElements[1], simplifiedElements[2:array_length(simplifiedElements,1)]);
  ELSE
    RETURN ST_Simplify(geom, tolerance);
  END IF;

END
$BODY$  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE
```

Comment: +1, very nice. I have no idea why you needed help with this, your spatial plpgsql is very good.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [ST_ConvexHull](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ConvexHull.html)? It should be perfect for this case:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_ConvexHull(ST_GeomFromText(
    'POLYGON((5 0, 10 0, 10 10, 0 10, 0 0, 5 0))'
    )))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I may have concave polygons. I tried ST_ConcaveHull but it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

This function does what you originally asked for. The general idea is to insert the 2nd point again, and then rearrange the linestring order so that this is the new start point and then to run simplify on this this new ordered linestring. It could be made more elegant, perhaps checking for repeated points and searching for an insertion point, enforcing geometry types and checking for validity,  but I believe it does what you asked for.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION simplify_movestart(geom geometry, tolerance float)  
  RETURNS geometry AS
$BODY$ 

declare linestring geometry;
declare dumped_points geometry[];
declare arr_len int;
declare x int;
declare fixed_geom geometry default 'LINESTRING EMPTY';

begin

  --get linestring from original polyon's outer ring
  linestring := st_exteriorring(geom);
  --add a new repeated point after start point 
  linestring := st_addpoint(linestring, st_pointn(linestring,2),2);

  --dump point to array
  dumped_points:=array(select (st_dumppoints(linestring)).geom);
  arr_len:= array_length(dumped_points,1);

  --create new linestring, starting from new start point
  for x in 3..arr_len  loop
     fixed_geom := st_addpoint(fixed_geom, dumped_points[x]);
  end loop;

  --add 1st and 2nd points at end
  fixed_geom := st_addpoint(fixed_geom, dumped_points[1], arr_len-2);
  fixed_geom := st_addpoint(fixed_geom, dumped_points[2], arr_len-1);

  --debug stuff
  raise notice 'new linestring : % ', st_astext(linestring);
  raise notice 'rearranged geom: %', st_astext(fixed_geom);
  --show simplified start point
  raise notice 'simplfied geom : %', st_astext(st_simplify(fixed_geom, $2));

  --return new, simplified polygon
  return st_makepolygon(st_simplify(fixed_geom, $2));

 end
$BODY$  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Testing with your original example polygons yields:

```
select st_astext(simplify_movestart(st_geomfromtext('POLYGON((5 0, 10 0, 10 10, 0 10, 0 0, 5 0))'),1));
NOTICE:  new linestring : LINESTRING(5 0,10 0,10 0,10 10,0 10,0 0,5 0) 
NOTICE:  rearranged geom: LINESTRING(10 0,10 10,0 10,0 0,5 0,5 0,10 0)
NOTICE:  simplfied geom : LINESTRING(10 0,10 10,0 10,0 0,10 0)
POLYGON((10 0,10 10,0 10,0 0,10 0))
```

**Note:** I added a tolerance parameter, as you have to set it a lot lower than 1 to work with the polygon you posted in the comments, to get it to simplify properly (with 1, you end up with a single point).

Comment: Sadly it seems not to work with these polygons : `POLYGON((0 0,5 0,10 0,8 8,10 10,0 10,0 0))` `POLYGON((0 5,0 2.5, 0 0,10 0,10 10,0 10,0 5))` `POLYGON((0 0,5 0,10 0,10 10,0 10,0 0))`

Comment: OK, yes, I see the problem. It is sensitive to where you add the extra point. This probably needs to be done recursively/iteratively, inserting a new point at each point in linestring, rearringing around that so you get a new start/end point, simplifying, and returning the one the has the smallest number of points. Sadly, I am getting ready to go away, and while it is quite an interesting problem, I lack time right now.

Comment: I started a github project to test everything: https://github.com/Volune/test-plpgsql-simplify . I'm about to have a working solution derived from your proposition.

Comment: Great. Glad I was some help.